# stop a systemd job and all activators

Tags: linux, systemd

i want to stop a job that is activated by sockets or files or whatnot, e.g.

```
# systemctl stop rsyslog
Warning: Stopping rsyslog.service, but it can still be activated by:
  syslog.socket
```

is there a way to stop it together with all activators, other than tracking them all down and stopping individually? I don't want to disable the job permanently, just stop it temporarily until it is explicitly started.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mask the job:

```
systemctl mask rsyslog
```

This will link the socket to `/dev/null` and thus remove the possibility to activate it via a socket.

Comment: Nope, doesnt seem to do anything # systemctl mask rsyslog
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/rsyslog.service → /dev/null.
# systemctl stop rsyslog
Warning: Stopping rsyslog.service, but it can still be activated by:
  syslog.socket
~# systemctl status rsyslog
● rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; masked; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-08-12 17:50:37 UTC; 5s ago
     Docs:

Comment: The "can still be activated by: syslog.socket" is to be expected, but this socket is dead. Have you tried killing it (or just reboot) ?

Comment: Yes, when killed systemd just restarts it, I don't want to reboot, as per my question "I don't want to disable the job permanently, just stop it temporarily until it is explicitly started."

Answer (score 1):

This command should do the trick

```
systemctl disable --now rsyslog.service
```

sometimes two services are connected, for instance to stop docker service we'd have touse

```
 systemctl disable --now docker.service docker.socket
```